# How to replace contents in file in python

Tags: python, file

I have a script in python, part of the script involves me creating a .txt file with contents i will need to use throughout the script

```
my_file = open('number.txt', 'w')
my_file.write(str(30))
my_file.close()
```

There are two things i'm stuck on, firstly, considering there will only ever be one number in the file, how would i open it and assign the contents to a variable. I know to open the file and read it would be something like this:

```
my_file = open('number.txt', 'r')
```

but then i want to assign the contents which right now is 30 to a variable called 'num' which i could use throughout the rest of my script.

Secondly, how could i replace the contents of the file. as in re-open it and replace the 30 with a different number, and would this also change automatically for the variable aswell?

Comment: `data = open("number.txt", "r").read(); value = int(data)`

Comment: json ref: https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html?highlight=json#module-json  pickle ref: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html?highlight=json

Comment: if the file is maintained by your application, you could choose the format of the data. You could use json to write out variables and use json to read them back in later. Or you could use pickle to serialize objects to file and read them back in later. If you're just talking about one number in a file, that's pretty easy.